# How to convert POSIX epoch seconds to EST/EDT time reliably, with pure functions

Tags: haskell, time

I'm using the `time-1.5.0.1` library.

I'm given a value representing epoch seconds, e.g. `1449590820` which equals `2015-12-08 11:07:00 -0500`.

Using [Data.Time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time.html) modules, I want to be able to convert `1449590820` to a `ZonedTime`.

The function I want to use is this:

```
utcToZonedTime :: TimeZone -> UTCTime -> ZonedTime
```

The problem is getting the `TimeZone` value I need. The available functions in `Data.Time` either depend on getting the `TimeZone` from the environment or require you to explicitly construct a `TimeZone` for `EDT` or `EST`.

I want to avoid depending on the environment to give me a `ZonedTime`, because there is no guarantee that the code will run on a server set to the US Eastern Time. So using this function is out of the question:

```
utcToLocalZonedTime :: UTCTime -> IO ZonedTime
```

So that leaves me with the option of constructing the necessary `TimeZone` input myself.

But the `TimeZone` for `EDT` is not the same as the `TimeZone` for `EST`, so I need a different `TimeZone` depending on whether daylight savings is in effect. Is there is an easy way to generate a `TimeZone` of `EDT` or `EST` depending on the value of a `UTCTime` (i.e. whether it falls within the Daylight Savings Time period)?

I want to stress that I want to do this exclusively using pure functions.

Maybe I'm looking for a Haskell analog to the [tzinfo library in Ruby](https://github.com/glortho/tzinfo).

Comment: So you would want to pass the desired time zone and a UTC datetime value, and receive a value with the time zone set _and_ hours adjusted for daylight savings time, based on the zone you passed?

Comment: @9000 I'd be happy with just being able to get the daylight-savings-adjusted TimeZone value for any UTCTime in the U.S. Eastern Time Zone.

Comment: A cursory look through sources made me think that the library supposes `EDT` and `EST` two separate and unrelated timezones, and does not appear to have the DST start / end info which [tzdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) has. Raw tzdata are [available](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tzdata) but still raw,

Comment: Yes, it seems like I'm looking for tzdata/tzinfo support in Haskell.

Comment: I'm looking at this right now: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tz

Comment: There is also http://hackage.haskell.org/package/timezone-olson which seemingly contains the UTC offset rules in some form, but I failed to find an easily consumable form yet.

Comment: Whether daylight savings is in effect, GLOBALLY AND HISTORICALLY, is DIFFICULT to determine.  You could get all the old Olsen databases, but not everybody even agrees on all DST and timezones

Answer (score 0):

The [tz](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tz) package looks like it might fit the bill, but unfortunately, it has [dependency build problems](https://github.com/fpco/stackage/issues/907).

Answer (score 0):

`utcToLocalTime'` and `timeZoneFromSeries` from the [timezone-series](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/timezone-series-0.1.5.1/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime-TimeZone-Series.html#v:utcToLocalTime-39-) package look to have been developed to cover exactly this scenario.